# PyPDF2 Resize Text or image

Tags: python, pypdf

Can I resize text or image using PyPDF2 or other library without resizing the page?

I have no Idea what function to use because I cannot find it on the docs

```
import PyPDF2 as pypdf
pdf1File = open('output.pdf', 'rb')
pdf = pypdf.PdfFileReader(pdf1File)
page = pdf.pages[1]
contents = page.getContents()
......????
```

I want to resize objects at the right block

[image]

you can download pdf file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nf_7fo3LStVDRCqtKn-J_vOLs4xPQu_h/view)

Answer (score 1):

> Can I resize text or image using PyPDF2 or other library **without resizing the page?**

### pypdf >= 3.10.0

pypdf >= 3.10.0 can change the size of images:

```py
from pypdf import PdfReader, PdfWriter

from PIL import Image  # pip install pillow

reader = PdfReader("example.pdf")
writer = PdfWriter()
for page in reader.pages:
    writer.add_page(page)
for page in writer.pages:
    for img in page.images:
        img = img.image.resize((basewidth,hsize), Image.Resampling.LANCZOS)
        img.replace(img, quality=80)
with open("out.pdf", "wb") as f:
    writer.write(f)
```

### PyPDF2 / pypdf < 3.10.0

No, that is not possible with pypdf (or PyPDF2).

I'm the current maintainer of pypdf and PyPDF2.